# stl container end is redundant after find, so what is the shortcut

Tags: c++, stl

Let us assume we have a map class (unordered map, list, set, whatever will also do). We are looking for a specific element. After calling the find() member, we have to check with the end() member. But find() internally already knows whether it is returning a good iterator or the end iterator. Why should we need to call end() again? This adds some overhead.

```
std::map<int,float> myMap;
// some other code to populate the map
// ...
std::map<int,float>::iterator myIt;
myIt = myMap.find(2); // doesn't this already know wheter its returning the end() iterator?
if (myIt != myMap.end()) { //calling end() here wastes some time because find
                           //already knew the result
   std::cout << "Found, value is "<<(*myIt).second<<"\n";
} else {
   std::cout << "Not found.\n";
}
```

There should be a way to know what the result of find() is without calling end().

Comment: You are probably worrying too much about micro-performance.

Comment: Wastes time in comparison to what? You think a call to end() is expensive or somthing. You think the compiler may not have inlined that for you. What other interface can you propose that is more effecient?

Comment: With GCC 4.5 -O2 it doesn't call `.end()` at all. With -O3 even the `.find()` is inlined.

Comment: Write your code, get it working, look at generated assembly, observe profiling results, *then* wonder about speeding it up. PLEASE. If you have to ask if X is faster than Y, you aren't in a position to need to know whether X is faster than Y.

Comment: @Martin York:
How about a cheap bool iterator::isEnd(), that is computed during the call to find()?

Comment: In that case, the iterator would have to store additional information, increasing its size and making it more expensive to pass around every single time you use it.  It will also complicate the code that uses the iterator, because it will have to validate that the new member is updated properly.

Comment: @user429850: The iterator can't know if it's the end.  And the compiler will do a better job at optimizing this than you.

Comment: @user429850: You are making the iterator more expensive to create/copy to solve a single use case. Also this is unlikely to be more efficient than the current implementation as you are now looking up an object on the iterator rather than container (so zero gain).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternatives are possible - for example, find() could return a std::pair or something akin to boost::optional - but there's little practical advantage and it requires an uglier, more error prone coding style.  In languages (mainly interpreted) with an inbuilt None/null sentinel that's the ideal value for this, but C++ won't add that as there's a large cost in having a bool tagged on to every variable, and it's impractical to suddenly say "anyone wanting to store ints, listen up: -78 is hereafter reserved for end()/Null/whatever, please don't abuse it for other purposes".  Container classes are in the best (only) place to know which value is an appropriate sentinel that wouldn't make sense as a legal iterator and allows a trivial, lightning fast != test, or if it's necessary to tack on that bool and use more complex iterator structures: end() abstracts that, and will be inlined in practice mitigating your performance concerns.

Answer (score 7):

What else could it possibly return? It needs to return a valid iterator, but anything other than `end()` would refer to an actual element in the container. There really isn't a choice here.

Also, STL functions such as `end()` are usually inline and on top of that compilers do a fair bit of optimization, so that extra call isn't really a call.

Comment: While profiling one of my programs, I noticed that the end() call right after the find() call took 20% of the time of find(). So that is some 20% overhead. I understand conceptually find() returns a valid iterator, but isn't there a way to save on that 20% overhead?

Comment: I was using GCC 4.2. Thanks for the -O2 and -O3 suggestions. I agree that this is small micro-performance and not needed in 99% of the cases.

Comment: @user: Profiling without optimizations is completely meaningless.

Comment: @user429850: I think these comments should have gone above, where the questions were asked. Anyhow, I don't know how you profiled your code but the 20% figure seems quite wrong.

Comment: I agree, they should have gone above. I was profiling with Shark on MacOSX.